# MT7630E fail after days installation

Tags: networking, drivers

The drive Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter, fail after moreless 15 days after install, I  didn't upgrade my system, and now I can't connect wifi. I want one solution to resolve this problem forever, because I can solve this problem with a reinstallation, but it is annoying to be every 15 days to reinstall the same thing.

drive: Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter;
PC: ASUS X555L;

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  See various wi-fi access ports but can't connect to any of them? Is it that you can connect but your machine won't communicate with a site? If you only have one local access port available, have you gone to the local library or wi-fi hot spot and tried that wi-fi? Have you tried rebooting the router then rebooting the laptop to see if the router is the problem? Lastly, have you tried this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

Comment: Version of ubuntu is 16.04 LTS, and I don't have wifi, I have windows 10 with dual boot ubuntu, and on windows I have wifi. Yesterday I reinstalled drive, but my pc crashed in the installation, and now, when I try to log in ubuntu, it opens a terminal in "emergency mode", and I can't log in, I will format the system to solve it, but i know that the drive fails again after a few days.